# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2+\cos n}{1-\sqrt n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am solving this question but facing some difficulty:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2+\cos n}{1-\sqrt n}$$

[image]

I have to find whether this series converges or diverges.
I am a bit confused as the denominator can be negative so I cannot apply integral test and at `n=1 it goes infinity`.

Comment: Look at the term with $n=1$. Something is wrong here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you start from $n=2$,

**HINT**

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2+\cos n}{\sqrt{n}-1}\ge \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1}$$

Also, we have that $$\frac{{1}}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1}$$

For sufficiently large $n$.

Using the $p$-series, note $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1}$diverges.